# What does the "Armor" stat do in Geneforge 2?

Tags: geneforge-2

One of the many stats on your character sheet is "Armor". Just about any piece of clothing or armour will increase this. But what does it actually do? Presumably, it makes you harder to kill in some way, but I can't find any section of the in-game manual that explains how.

Ideally, I'd like to know the exact math behind Armor. Failing that, I would like to at least know whether it reduces enemy chance to hit, damage inflicted, or both, and what types of attacks it works against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, in Geneforge 1 & 2, armor reduces damage by a fixed amount. Whether it reduces it by exactly the armor value or if the armor value is used in a calculation to determine the amount it reduces, I do not recall. I believe it only works against physical attacks. It does not reduce the enemy's chance to hit.

In Geneforge 3-5, armor reduces by a percentage instead. This means armor doesn't scale with difficulty in Geneforge 2 like it does in the later games, which is why you'll feel like you're wearing tissue paper on Torment difficulty.

Comment: Awesome. Do you have a source, or is this just from your own experimentation with the game?

Comment: I played Geneforge 1-4 about 3 years ago so its mostly memory. But i did find [this thread](http://spiderwebforums.ipbhost.com/index.php?/topic/17718-mechanism-change-and-balance-of-geneforge-series/) which seemed to confirm it.